# How to select a line feature by clicking near it?

Tags: openlayers

I want to enable selecting line features in OpenLayer by clicking. How to select it by clicking on it or near it? For example: take a look at [Google map maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when features already are on the vectorLayer, you should be able to enable selecting them just by using [selectFeature](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html) control.

When you only use WMS on your map, you have tu write a [request](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/getfeature-wfs.html) to get the features through WFS as [WKT](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/docs/examples/wkt.html) from your map server, add them to a vectorLayer and use the above selectFeature control to select/highlight them.